# How to extract specific data from JSON file

Tags: json

I have this database http://ashleyw.co.uk/project/food-nutrient-database, and I would like to extract the group `Dairy and Egg Products` into a separate Json file.

Also, within the group some of the data is triplicated. For example:

```
{
    "id": 1008,
    "description": "Cheese, caraway",
    "tags": [],
    "manufacturer": "",
    "group": "Dairy and Egg Products",
    "portions": [
        {
            "amount": 1,
            "unit": "oz",
            "grams": 28.35
        }
    ],
    "nutrients": [
        {
            "value": 25.18,
            "units": "g",
            "description": "Protein",
            "group": "Composition"
        },
        {
            "value": 29.2,
            "units": "g",
            "description": "Total lipid (fat)",
            "group": "Composition"
        },
        {
            "value": 3.06,
            "units": "g",
            "description": "Carbohydrate, by difference",
            "group": "Composition"
        },
        {
            "value": 25.18,
            "units": "g",
            "description": "Protein",
            "group": "Composition"
        },
        {
            "value": 29.2,
            "units": "g",
            "description": "Total lipid (fat)",
            "group": "Composition"
        },
        {
            "value": 3.06,
            "units": "g",
            "description": "Carbohydrate, by difference",
            "group": "Composition"
        },
        {
            "value": 25.18,
            "units": "g",
            "description": "Protein",
            "group": "Composition"
        },
        {
            "value": 29.2,
            "units": "g",
            "description": "Total lipid (fat)",
            "group": "Composition"
        },
        {
            "value": 3.06,
            "units": "g",
            "description": "Carbohydrate, by difference",
            "group": "Composition"
        }
    ]
}
```

Every child of the `nutrients` node is triplicated. How can the extras be stripped away?

Comment: Maybe try [jq](http://stedolan.github.io/jq/) if you want a CLI tool :)

Comment: @LutzHorn I am most familiar with JavaScript. Although I am new to programming in general. Can you explain your code?

Answer (score 0):

Using [Python](http://docs.python.org/3.3/library/json.html):

```
import json

with open("data.json") as f, open("nutrients.json", "w") as g:
    d = json.loads(f.read())
    json.dump(d["nutrients"], g)
```